# Who is Claude Morlet?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, biography

[Please delete if off-topic.]

I would be curious to find out more about the life and mathematical achievements of the French topologist Claude Morlet.

The internet told me he got his PhD in 1968 with Cartan and Haefliger.

Besides a survey article in 1981, he seems to have published only in the 60s and 70s. He proved important results that are used a lot in current research like his "disjunction" and "comparison" lemma/theorem. They are now named after him, but were partly written up by others.

Where was Morlet based, and is there an explanation why he stopped publishing? Is he still alive?

Comment: [Apparently](http://apmeplorraine.fr/IMG/pdf/nombre_d_or_et_cathedrale_de_metz_v2017.pdf) Claude Morlet was director of the IREM de Lorraine in 1980 (though perhaps a better source for this might be found).

Comment: here is his Ph.D. thesis: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1968_4_1_3_313_0.pdf

Comment: I cannot be completely sure that this is him, but the period matches: Claude Morlet, born 3 January 1934, passed away 14 November 2015 [(announcement)](http://memoire.lavoixdunord.fr/espace/monsieur-claude-morlet/352123); zbMath lists [his contributions](https://www.zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai%3Amorlet.claude).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker This is not very relevant to his life, perhaps, but I don't think I'd previously seen a PhD thesis in mathematics open with a quote by Mao Zedong!

Comment: He was also director of the "Département de mathématiques de Nancy" around 1975 (in French this usually means the teaching structure, not the math department, although I'm not 100% sure here): https://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/files/2021/03/Un_siecle_de_Mathematiques_a_Nancy.pdf He has written two math books for students: https://data.bnf.fr/en/12190155/claude_morlet/

Comment: Obligatory reminder:  this is what [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) is for.

Comment: I could easily find $>5$ people called Claude Morlet, mostly born in the same period (where the first name "Claude" [was a bit fashionable](http://www.prenomstat.com/?nameKey=Claude)). So the occurrence by of one particular person with this name is only with little probability the same person. The best would be to get in touch with the [IREM of Lorraine](http://irem.univ-lorraine.fr/)